# How to estimate the point of divergence between two continuous time survival curves?

Tags: time-series, survival, change-point

In this experiment we collect $N$ samples and each sample yields a pair of survival curves. The two survival curves are hypothesized to be identical up until time $t$ and diverge thereafter. What would be an appropriate method by which such a point $t$ can be estimated and statistically validated?

Answer (score 2):

There is some ambiguity in what the OP means by the "pair of survival curves" obtained from each of the "N samples."

If the "survival curves" are changes in the value of some continuous variable as a function of time from a maximum initial value down to zero for two cases or two groups within each of the N samples, then any of a variety of change-point approaches could work in principle, as suggested in another answer. The task would be simplified if there were an underlying theoretical model, such as exponential decay with a time constant that changes for one of the pair during the period of observation.

If the "survival curves" are time-to-event data for two groups distinguished within each of the N samples, then the problem is more complicated. A survey of [change-point packages in R](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/packages.html) found only [one](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=segmented) that accepts survival models, with an approach that is "not guaranteed to work," according to its manual, for model types other than `lm` or `glm`. Even that package does not meet the requirements of the OP, as it looks for change-points for regression coefficients within values of a continuous *predictor variable*, not for change points in *time* as the OP seeks.

So for time-to-event data what's needed is a way to search for the time of a *step change* in the relationship between the group membership within each sample and survival. For a Cox survival model that would be the time of a step change in the regression coefficient for `group`, where `group` represents which pair within a sample the data are from. The flexible survival regression approaches provided by the [`timereg` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=timereg) seem to be designed for coefficients that are continuous functions of time rather than step functions, but might serve this purpose. Alternatively, there might be ways to adapt the approach to step-function coefficient changes described in the [time-dependent vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) for the R `survival` package. As that splits data into strata based on the suspected time of the step change there would have to be some iterative approach to estimate the actual divergence time, and I'm not sure what would need to be done to estimate confidence intervals or to avoid overfitting with that approach.

Finally, for distinguishing when Kaplan-Meier survival curves diverge, the [`bpcp` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=bpcp) uses the individual KM curves to estimate their differences and associated CI at fixed times. Applied over a set of times, that approach could be used to determine estimated survival differences over time. Change-point analysis might then identify a time of divergence from 0 difference. Bootstrapping could presumably "statistically validate" the results.

Comment: The sample size required for reliable estimation of such change points is quite large.  Before getting too far into it compute the confidence band for the difference in two Kaplan-Meier cumulative incidence functions to see the information limit in your data.

Comment: Another complication is that the true separation could well be smooth rather than step-like, in which case the estimated separation will systematically be estimated earlier with larger sample sizes.

Answer (score 0):

One method that might be useful is change point detection.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection

There are many variants, but in general you partition the data into two sets and compute a test statistic, such as the Kolmogov-Smirnov, to determine whether the two distributions are the same.  If null hypothesis is rejected, there is a break or "change point" at time t.  In order to determine all such times, the test is repeated for each time step.

Comment: This looks like good general advice.  However, because a *survival curve* isn't exactly a "distribution" and is used when data are censored, this question appears to require some specific insight and methods tailored for these special characteristics.  Would you have any to recommend?